# 'resource' function evaluates either way and fails

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have a parent ARM template (eg: `app.assembly.json`) that

- takes multiple parameters, including:

  - `hostBindingName`
  - `certificatePfxBase64`

then later, the `resources` section, invokes multiple linked templates, each of which is single file, focused on a single resource allocation.

- `web.server.json`,
- `web.site.json`,
- `web.certificate.json`,
- `web.site.hostnamebinding.json'
- etc.

There are dependencies, such that

- `web.site.hostnamebinding` `dependsOn` `web.site`, and (optionally) `web.certificate`.

The problem is the *optional* certificate:

- one does not want to run a certificate template if there is no base64 pfx to provide it... .
- but hostnamebinding can proceed if there is a hostname -- it just can't be provided the cert parameters such as thumbprint, etc. if no cert was installed.

**First attempt: conditional certificate + dynamic dependsOn property on hostnamebinding.**

The first approach was to put a `conditional` within the parent `app.assembly.json` on the certificate resource reference, such that if `pfxBlob64` was empty, don't invoke the linked template.

Since the template was now optional, went off to make the `hostnameBinding`s resource's dependsOn conditional, something like the following pseudocode:

```
dependsOn: ...if (pfxBase64, array('website', 'certificate'), array('website')
```

But that gave errors saying it could not convert the array to a string[]...

I gave up.

**Second approach: take the conditional off the top level reference to the linked template, and put the conditional inside the linked template**

Second approach was to make both linked templates run either way -- removing the need for a dynamic `dependsOn` -- an simply put the conditional logic on the resource *within* the linked template.

Now...Final trick, get back from the nested template the thumbprint.

The following *should* have worked. whether I did the cert or didn't. It works when I provide pfxBase64...but fails when it not provided.

After some investigation, it appears that `reference` is evaluated either way.

Any recommendation on a different approach?

```
  "value":"[if (variables('web').certificate.conditionalFlag ,  reference(resourceId(variables('web').certificate.resourceType, variables('web').certificate.resourceName), '2015-08-01', 'Full').properties.thumbprint ,'')]"
```

.

**Third approach: duplicate but slightly different linked templates**

Another option I'm mulling is to return just the resourceId. 
And then use two different child templates for certs. One that sets the SSL, and one that doesn't set the SSL parameters...and only within the SSL setting child template, use the resource() method.
This feels so convoluted of a hack that I'd appreciate an alt suggestion before I try this messy approach.

Addendum:

**Fourth Approach:**

I'm currently going down the route of having two child templates, and using a dynamic path, switching between them based on a given condition:

- `web.certificate.json` which invokes resources, but that's fine as pfxBase64 was provided.
- `web.certificate.null.json`, which just returns ""

Seems to work :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant really do anything about it. ARM Templates are extremely stupid most of the times. Both sides of `if()` are evaluated and have to exist.

also, you cant have expressions for `dependsOn` (another extremely stupid limitation).

as for your problem, you have to pass in the `certificatePfxBase64` to the nested template (even if its empty) and if its empty not create a certificate. so use `json('null')` instead of a `''`.

Comment: Thanks. Good ideas. I ended up installing the cert on all sites. (proving it was working in ST/UAT) and only doing hostnamebinding (which does not gen an output) in PROD.. 

Yes...they really are "extremely stupid most of the time" ;-) I've never found a way to conditionally create a new resource (storageAccount), and then conditionally reference it to add keys to the keyvault only if created. Drives me batso.